# Recover screen recording that had destination set to SD card that was unmounted

Tags: macos, hard-drive, video, external-disk, data-recovery

I was using a program called iShowU Instant to create a screen recording on my Mac and the destination was set to the SD card in the Mac's built in SD card reader.

The Mac's battery died and the computer went into safe sleep mode.

I plugged the Mac in and turned it back on and iShowU still showed that it was running with the green record icon and time elapsing in the menu bar.

However, because the screen was being recorded, notifications were not showing up including that the SD card had been ejected. When I turned the Mac back on, the SD card had not re-mounted.

The screen recording appeared to continue but the actual save location was not present. Once I realized this I pulled the SD card out and put it back in which mounted it again. I then stopped the screen recording, and it gave an error message of some sort (it was long and I don't recall what it said).

I used video recovery software called Treasured that recovered the part of the unopenable file that was created up until the point the computer turned off when the SD card unmounted.

I am wondering if there is anywhere on the internal SSD that the rest of the file might have been saved since the application appeared to continue recording even when the SD card was not mounted?

I also had a setting turned on that says "Save recording periodically" and is set to every 60 seconds.

Comment: That would be a question for the developer of the recording software you were using.